# How to set repeater from protractor?

Tags: angular, protractor, e2e-testing, angularjs-e2e, angular-e2e

```
<md-tab *ngFor="let course of profCourses>
   <div class="wrapper">
        <!--some html-->
   </div>
</md-tab>
```

I want to set profCourses from protractor and test the functionality of inner html. How to set such binding from protractor?

Is it something like

```
element.all(by.repeater('let course of profCourses')).then(function (courses) {
       courses[0].sendKeys('Course 1');
       courses[1].sendKeys('Course 2');
       courses[2].sendKeys('Course 3');
    });
```

I am getting error for above as  "Cannot read property 'sendKeys' of undefined"

PS: I am using Angular 4.0

Comment: ng-repeater will not work with angular version 2 & 4. refer https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/3205.

Answer (score 0):

The correct code would be

```
   courses.get(0).sendKeys('Course 1');
   courses.get(1).sendKeys('Course 2');
   courses.get(2).sendKeys('Course 3');
```